# JPA and Hibernate, OneToMany relationship with a composite key using UUID

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using SpringBoot with JPA and Hibernate.

I have two entities: Book and Author. A Book can have multiple Authors. So I need a OneToMany relationship.

Into the Author table, my idea is to use a composite key (the book_id and one internal field for example field_a)

I implemented these classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book extends MyBaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author extends MyBaseEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CustomID id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @MapsId("bookId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Book book;

    @Column(name = "field_a", nullable = false)
    @MapsId("fieldA")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID fieldA;

}


@Embeddable
public class CustomID implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private UUID bookId;

    @Column(name = "field_a")
    private UUID fieldA;

    public CustomID() { }

    public CustomID(UUID bookId, UUID fieldA) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        ShareID that = (CustomID) o;
        return Objects.equals(bookId, that.bookId) &&
                Objects.equals(fieldA, that.fieldA);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(bookId, fieldA);
    }
}
```

When I try to execute my project (I'm using the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` to generate the DB) I'm obtaining this error:

```
ERROR SpringApplication-reportFailure():837 - [ Application run failed ]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown entity name: java.util.UUID
```

Any suggestion?

If I try to remove the use of composite-key works fine so, probably the problem it's related to the implementation or use of the composite key.

Comment: Question  unrelated to your actual question: Do you really want a `Book` to have many `Author`s, but one `Author` can only be in relation to one `Book`?

Comment: Yes, probably I not used the most appropriate example... but into my real scenario the relationship it's correct

Comment: Just asking, because entity structure-wise it looks like you took a working many-to-many relation setup and tried to convert it to a one-to-many setup. The composite key doesn't make much sense to me from an entity design perspective, why not just directly map to the book in the author entity?

Comment: but maybe that's also because I've been using too much Spring Data abstraction and didn't use JPA for too long ^^

Comment: @Safari Please show `CustomID`. What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK about CustomID the code already there. I'm using Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final

Comment: The problem is you have two mappings for the UUID 'fieldA'. MapsId is used for relationship mappings, to which fieldA is not, telling JPA to use the primary key from this referenced entity to set the value within the embedded ID you pointed it at - 'fieldA'. Just remove this outright from the Author class, and use author.id.fieldA when ever you need to use that UUID.

Comment: @kasoban Yes, you caught me! I started from a M2M relationship. In my case my idea is to use a composite key because I would like to avoid to use an additional primary key (for example as long int or UUID). I would like to use one pair (book_id, flied_a) because these will be unique

Comment: @Chris can you show me an example using an answer for your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either an ID class with Author as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
@IdClass(CustomID.class)
public class Author extends MyBaseEntity {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Book book;

    @ID
    @Column(name = "field_a", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID fieldA;

}

public class CustomID implements Serializable {
    //these match the names of the property marked with @Id in Author
    private UUID book;
    private UUID fieldA;
}
```

Or an embeddable that defines the basic fields for your entity as you have already done:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author extends MyBaseEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CustomID id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @MapsId("bookId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Book book;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, are there some additional aspects about your two proposed solutions that it's better to take in mind? For example, is there a better solution related to performances, or more clean solution or other?

Comment: This is something you'll have to investigate based on your usecases, caching, and how your provider handles the fetching. The embeddedID means you can access author.id.bookId without having to query using author.book.id - so it depends on how your provider handles that and if it preforms an inner join or not, and it might make it easier to access the book id without having to fetch the book itself. Otherwise, I don't like embeddable, but that is a personal preference with no real good reason for (legacy pains mostly long since dealt with in most ORM providers).

Comment: using your first solution, into the DB, about book_id column I see values like this: `éÄH&MmRàù¿Û`
Why? It's possible to have the id value for the related entity Book?

Comment: In both solutions Book_Id is a foreign key, so any value it contains must come from the book table ID column. I don't know why you would see values like that from a UUID.